# Diferencia entre servidor de base de datos y motor de base de datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Buenos dias, tal vez pueda resultar una pregunta bastante trivial, pero la realidad es que muchas personas la ultilizan indiferentemente y quisiera saber si refieren exactamente a lo mismo, o si existe una diferencia tecnica.

Por lo que tengo entendido, ambas forman parte de un sistema de gestion de base de datos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: depende demasiado del autor, toma en cuenta que por ejemplo, microsoft toma ambas deficiones para lo mismo, pero otros autores los diferencian, aquí hay un sitio donde puedes leer al respecto. [enlace](http://www.softwareintegrado.com/diferencias-entre-base-de-datos-microsoft/)

Answer (score 3):

Se llama motor, a las herramientas que permiten comunicarse con la base de datos, ejecutan los procesos sobre las tablas y mantienen la integridad de los datos. El motor es quien interpreta y ejecuta las consultas, mantiene los indices, entre muchas otras cosas.

Por servidor, en general se entiende al entorno físico (al hardware) donde reside un motor de base de datos. Sin embargo, como en general en los grandes lugares las maquinas que albergan bases de datos, solo tienen al motor de la base de datos, entonces por eso se usa indistintamente.

Sin embargo, podrías tranquilamente tener un motor de base de datos instalado en tu pc, y que a su vez sirvieras a otras PC, con lo que tu PC seria tambien el servidor de base de datos.